# install chrome on aws ec2 linux server?

Tags: chrome, aws

I am trying to install google chrome using `yum install google-chrome-stable`
but it is giving me this error on libgdk and libgtk.

```
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-61.0.3163.100-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-61.0.3163.100-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

When I ran:

```
yum install libgtk-3 -y; yum install google-chrome-stable -y
```

I got:

> No package libgtk-3 available

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by installing an RPM directly:

```
sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall https://intoli.com/blog/installing-google-chrome-on-centos/google-chrome-stable-60.0.3112.113-1.x86_64.rpm
```